# Auto Refresh div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, graphael, justgage

I have a gage that refreshes and gets random data every time I click a button.

My question is how can I do this without clicking the button, I want it to Auto refresh every 5 seconds.

```
 <div id="gg1" class="gauge">
</div>
<a href="#" id="gg1_refresh" class="button grey">Random Refresh</a>
<script>
    var gg1 = new JustGage({
        id: "gg1",
        donut: 1,
        title: "BARTOW",
        titleFontColor: "#000000",
        value: 95.7,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,           
        labelFontColor: "#000000",
        humanFriendlyDecimal: 1,
        decimals: 1,
        symbol: "%",
        refreshAnimationType: "bounce",
        gaugeWidthScale: 0.6,
        customSectors: [{
            color: "#ff0000",
            lo: 0,
            hi: 79
        }, {
            color: "#ffa500",
            lo: 80,
            hi: 89
        }, {
            color: "#1eae1e",
            lo: 90,
            hi: 100
        }],
        counter: true
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#gg1_refresh').bind('click', function () {
            gg1.refresh(getRandomInt(0, 100));
            return false;

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Use this link : http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_refresh_page.cfm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following, edited per @thenewseattle's comment.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function refreshDiv() {
       gg1.refresh(getRandomInt(0, 100));
    }
    $(document).ready(function () { setInterval(refreshDiv, 5000); });
</script>
```

Comment: -1 the OP is asking for setInterval. not setTimeout.

Comment: You shouldn't have changed it in my opinion. `setTimeout` is much better/safer as `setInterval` runs indiscriminately and doesn't care whether your script has completed or not, meaning you could be calling the function faster than it can complete. Its much better to use `setTimeout()` but you should clear it before reusing it with `clearTimeout()`

Comment: Yeah, I was of the opinion that setTimeout() was better if you're updating based upon anything not-instantaneous, as you don't want to stack up a bunch of refresh calls which haven't completed.  However, the OP's example is an instantaneous refresh, so I think it's safe in this instance.  Either way, there's definitely an argument for setTimeout() too, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to call a function every 5 seconds.

You will need to create a function that contains the code

```
gg1.refresh(getRandomInt(0, 100));
```

And then use the setInterval function in your click event handler to call the function you created above.

Comment: I am new to javascript. How do I do this?

Comment: There is a sample on the page that allows you to use the javascript function. I'm not going to write the code out for you as I believe it isn't the way to learn. I've included a description in my answer on what you'll need to do

Comment: @Apollo google jquery setInterval you will find the necessary information

Comment: @thenewseattle setInterval isn't a jQuery function, it's a standard javascript function that doesn't require any library.

Comment: @SandeepBansal that's right. but the OP is already using jQuery in his question.